# how to calculate sum of all values in a dictionary, that's also nested in a list?

Tags: list, dictionary

after opening csv file i cant figure out hot to proceed to calculate the sum of all 86 entries in a dictionary that's nested in a list data =  [{'Date': 'Jan-2010', 'Profit/Losses': '867884'}, {'Date': 'Feb-2010', 'Profit/Losses': '984655'}]?

I tried loops but wont work, I've tried extracting key and values methods but
I get errors suggesting that I work with a list not dictionary

need help if anyone even understands what I am asking :)

Comment: Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to put enough information into your question so we can help you.  Nested loops should work fine if written properly.  Show some of the input data and how you are trying to parse it (your code).  Also, add tags for the programming language and any parsing library you're using.

Comment: What programming language are you using? How do you read your csv? Please post your code. 'Profit/Losses' should probably not be imported as string...